# ISO standards implement in Software Quality assurance/testing

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-design, quality-center, data-quality

Please help that how to implement the ISO standards in SOFTWARE QUAILTY"" if any one has any template about these, share me please. I have read about the ISO/IEC 9126 but don't know how to implement in software quality assurance, how to create matrices or how to use in process. Please like and help

Comment: ISO/IEC 9126 has been withdrawn and replaced by ISO/IEC 25010:2011. See here: http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=22749

Answer (score 3):

The ISO 9126 has some kind of templates for its own implementation: metrics that can be used for each quality characteristics, guidelines for the measurement process and usage of the standard. You will need a full version of the standard to get it, because these are rarely described in the comments on the standard. So buy it, or grab a copy in your company if they bought it already.

Still, even with the standard recommendations it is not easy to implement it practically. For a real-world implementation, you probably have to fall back on specific tools. I know that [SQuORE](http://www.squoring.com/en/produits/tableau-de-bord-squore/) implements it, but other products may have an implementation of the ISO 9126 (or even ISO/IEC 250xx) too. In those cases, you rely on the company's knowledge and experience to fill the gap between the standard's definition and its actual implementation.

Please note that the SQALE quality assessment method provides interesting and practical templates, and it is based on the ISO 9126 standard for the quality model. As for open-source software, SonarQube proposes something quite close, but IMHO not as complete as the aforementioned proprietary tools.

The [PolarSys maturity assessment](http://dashboard.castalia.camp) initiative also defines its product quality according to the ISO 9126 quality attributes, and uses open-source stuff only (Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to this last project).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9126) and searching online (there seem to be a lot of diagrams) it seems like the standard tries to set up a model using five (to 8) characteristics that are sub-divided into sub-characteristics.

If I were you I'd mindmap the characteristics and sub-characteristics (although you could also just list them in a document) and use them as guideword heuristics to generate test ideas. If you generate test ideas from the characteristics you could make the case you were trying to implement the ideas.

For example for the main characteristic of Portability and the sub-characteristic of Installability - you would hope to answer questions about the installability of the application you are testing. Does it install on all the platforms listed in the spec? Does it install the customer might expect it to install on? Does the application uninstall? Is the application easy to configure when installing (think custom install).

The idea is you want to understand the characteristics enough to apply them to your application. Think of them and generate questions you want to answer by testing or exploring your application.

Comment: Please share a template for guide???

Comment: I've never used this - I'm only trying to help. You can create a template by using the information on the wikipedia page under quality model and then brainstorming ideas / characteristics. I'm not going to do the work for you. =)

Answer (score 1):

Purely in relation to [ISO/IEC/IEEE 29119](http://www.softwaretestingstandard.org/) (The New International Software Testing Standard):

There's [mixed opinion](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/750/will-the-new-iso-iec-29119-software-testing-standard-work-with-agile-methodologi) on ISO/IEC/IEEE 29119, but it does provide a versatile framework that can help/suggest structure to a QA/test team. Standards aren't everything - efficient and effective testing should be your first priority.

If ISO-29119 is of interest, there's a lot to read, so I would start with ISO 29119-3 (Test Documentation) to get an idea of what/why test documentation is created. Get a feel for the hierarchy/structure of test documents (when/where/why they should be created), and it might also be worth having a think about how/whether test docs could be created dynamically in your organisation (or at least via templates) to save creation time.

Beyond that, ISO 29119-2 (Test Processes) should then make more sense, and help you understand what activities you might need to consider (that you may not have previously). Personally, I find 29119-2 weighty, but it gives an indication of the procedural approach/activities involved within test processes.

Having read and understood 29119-2 and 29119-3, the rest of the standard should be somewhat clearer and give you an idea of what changes are required within your organisation to help improve the structure of your test planning, processes and documentation. Where possible, consider your organisations existing software development practices/methodologies too.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another new standard rogarding softwore testing: ISO/IEC/IEEE 29119 Software Testing (http://www.softwaretestingstandard.org/)

Comment: The question is how to implement the standards - could you please edit your answer to describe how one might implement this new standard so that you've answered the question? Thanks, and welcome